# Azure DevOps, extra packages in Artifact Feed

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package

My CI pipeline is building a C# project, packing the outcome as a NuGet package and finally pushing the outcome to my Artifact feed.

After pushing the NuGet package to my feed, other packages are added too.

[image]

Is there a way to prevent that? Is this behavior related to the [Upstream Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops) specified when creating a new feed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Azure DevOps, extra packages in Artifact Feed

That because your private Nuget Feed set `nuget.org` as an Upstream source by default if you set Package from public sources enable when you create the this feed:

[image]

**When we download any packages from the Upstream sources, it will been cached in the Artifacts, you will see  and use it next time without download it again.**

You could use the source filter to select the source of the package:

[image]

To prevent that, you could select the radio button **Only use packages published to this feed** when you configure your private feed.

For those feed which you select the option use packages from public sources through this feed, you could delete the **Upstream sources** from setting->Feed settings->Upstream sources, select that upstream source you want to delete. BTW, for those packages that are already cached, you need to manually delete them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

When a feed is configured to function as an upstream proxy, any packages requested will be downloaded from NuGet.org or npmjs.org and added to the feed to speed up future access.

When you disable the Upstream Sources option, the feed will only hold what you explicitly put in it.